# Does TORQUE work on heteregenous clusters

Tags: scheduler, torque

Does [TORQUE](http://www.adaptivecomputing.com/products/open-source/torque/) work on heteregenous clusters?
I would like to use as cluser a set of old servers I have at home, but they do not have the same characteristics (number of cpus, memory, etc..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Torque schedules jobs to a cluster where each node has an individual set of attributes collected by the PBS agents on the nodes. Those attributes include

- `ncpus` - number of CPU cores
- `physmem` - amount of physical memory
- `totmem` - amount of available memory including swap

The following two attributes are used for scheduling decisions

- `np` - number of processing units (by default it is set to `ncpus`)
- `gpus` - number of graphics accelerators

Additional boolean properties can be set by the cluster administrator to help users and administrators influence node selection. Thus if you have a cluster with nodes with different CPU count Torque can ensure that nodes will not be overloaded by matching job requirements with available cpus on the nodes.